# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException on postgres connection

Tags: c#, postgresql, xamarin.forms, socketexception

I have this app where I connect to a Postgres DB. I have my Connection function, but every time I try to connect to the DB i get the exception:

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection refused  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect (Npgsql.NpgsqlTimeout timeout) [0x001f5] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:733   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+d__153.MoveNext () [0x005a0] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:648 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+d__149.MoveNext () [0x003e1] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:455 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Npgsql.ConnectorPool+d__19.MoveNext () [0x001cf] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\ConnectorPool.cs:300 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00022] in <1d288dd8ebaf4c6f890e1e99a5a184f0>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <1d288dd8ebaf4c6f890e1e99a5a184f0>:0   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection+<>c__DisplayClass32_0+<g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext () [0x0046d] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:331 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:153   at App1.MainPage.conexao () [0x00054] in C:\Users\Mario\Documents\projetos\App1\App1\App1\MainPage.xaml.cs:40 }

here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
   private void conexao()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection pgsqlConnection = null;
        var connString = string.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                             serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (pgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
            {
                usuario usuario = new usuario();
                // abre a conexão com o PgSQL e define a instrução SQL
                pgsqlConnection.Open();
                string cmdSeleciona = "Select * from funcionarios order by id_funcionario";
                List<string> lista = new List<string>();
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdSeleciona, pgsqlConnection);
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    usuario.nome_funcionario = reader["nome_funcionario"].ToString();
                    usuario.email = reader["email"].ToString();
                }
                //using (NpgsqlDataAdapter Adpt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdSeleciona, pgsqlConnection))
                //{
                //}
            }
        }
        catch (NpgsqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            pgsqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

The exception occurs on:`pgsqlConnection.Open();`

Comment: "Connection refused" - is your connection string correct, is the server running, have you ruled out network connectivity problems, etc?  ie, have you done any basic debugging?

Comment: I've created a Windows forms app and managed to connect fine, I don't think its something with the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

This question is open for over a year so I dare to give a less concrete answer about things you could check...

**Check the following things:**

1. Win+R services.msc or go into taskmanager and check if the postgresql service is started
2. Run PgAdmin which opens in the browser. If PgAdmin can connect and you can browse your db you can rule out a lot.
3. Check your connection string and make sure the user has all roles (if you just want to test just give him all permissions via pgadmin)

If you are using a dockerized environment you need to set the containers into the same network and use `host.docker.internal` instead of localhost as host.

Here an example of my working connection string of my linux docker container environment:

```
host=host.docker.internal;port=5432;database=mydatabase;username=userxyz;password=password123
```